# Server was unable to process request

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have made web service, when it is accessed by remote computer to send me the data using this web service then the following errors shows on the remote computer:-

"Server was unable to process request..A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

Answer (score 2):

That is a connectionstring or network permission issue.  When you deploy make sure the config associated with the webservice contains a valid connectionstring to reach your database.  Ensure you are using SQL server authentication with an appropriate user and password and that the SQL server is accessible from the webservice deployment machine.

Comment: Or make sure that the server has network access to the database.

Comment: @oded: Realized that as I clicked save and edited to include that possibility.